# Get site data written on reactjs with the help of guzzlehttp

Tags: php, reactjs, guzzle6, guzzle

There is a certain website, or rather one page, and which has a table obtained with the help of reactjs. I need to get data from this table. Can I do this with guzlehttp? How?

The data in this table is not loaded by a separate query (I can not track it). That is, tables appear together with the loading of the page (or a little later). But the source code of the page does not have this data. These data are not present in the scripts connected on this page.

As in theory, I can get this data with the help of the Guzzlehttp library. Now I get only the source code of the page. But of course there is no such data.